# Is this a correct way to structure a REST api?

Tags: api, rest

I'm developing a REST api where i can fetch the data about some medical products. Everything works fine, but when i look at the structure of the response i don't know if it's an optimal way of structuring the data. Some products have children, and those children can have children too, so i end up with something like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": "4",
        "name": "Hands and wrists",
        "children": [
            {
                "id": "6",
                "name": "Medical Gloves",
                "parent_id": "4"
            },
            {
                "id": "5",
                "name": "Patient Wristband",
                "parent_id": "4"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

The problem comes when the data starts having more than two hierarchy levels, is this a correct way of structuring this particular REST api?

```
[
    {
        "id": "4",
        "name": "Hands and wrists",
        "children": [
            {
                "id": "6",
                "name": "Medical Gloves",
                "parent_id": "4"
            },
            {
                "id": "5",
                "name": "Patient Wristband",
                "parent_id": "4",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "id": "20",
                        "name": "Left Hand Wristband",
                        "parent_id": "5"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Having so many levels of nested data will affect how the client of the api will consume it? Or is it okay to structure the data following this approach?

Comment: You should design the interaction and payload exchanged as if you'd implement a Web page. The media-type exchanged should define the syntax and semantics of the fields/elements/attributes/... that may appear in the payload hence a client only needs to know how to operate on that generic representation format, that can easily be used to represent other resources as well, but not the API itself. Not the API is the important part, but the payloads you exchange. Hence, your approach is not REST but some proprietary Web-RPC stuff where the design depends soley on your preferences

Answer (score 1):

It's absolutely fine to have that structure. I would say even this implementation will be in most of the REST api.
It's an object graph. Or in domain-driven design, it's called aggregate or composition accordantly.
Therefore having an object graph, with deeply nested objects is fine.
Regarding consuming this object on the client-side, of course you have to handle that accordantly on the client side as well, to take care of all nested objects.